# How to find a certain property from an object in Java

Tags: java, search, object

So I'm making a book class, each book has a title, author, etc... So what I want to do is make a method that searches through all the properties of my objects and finds my query. For example

```
public void titleSearch(String query)
{
    find Book with query title
}
```

I'm not sure is this is a duplicate but I didn't know what to search for.

Thanks for your help. Let me know if you need more of my code.

Answer (score 0):

Look at [JXPath](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-jxpath/) library.
With JXpath you can use Xpath queries to  search graphs of objects.

Consider this example of searhing all addressses with zipCode=90210:

```
Address address = (Address)JXPathContext.newContext(vendor).
         getValue("locations[address/zipCode='90210']/address");
```

This XPath expression is equivalent to the following Java code:

```
Address address = null;
Collection locations = vendor.getLocations();
Iterator it = locations.iterator();
while (it.hasNext()){
    Location location = (Location)it.next();
    String zipCode = location.getAddress().getZipCode();
    if (zipCode.equals("90210")){
      address = location.getAddress();
      break;
    }
}
```